# Convert string in array format to array

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object, properties

I have an object structured like.

```
{
  details[0][test1]: "text1"
  details[0][test2]: "text2"
  details[0][test3]: "text3"
  details[0][test4]: "text4"
}
```

What I want is to convert the properties into array so that "details"
becomes an associative array.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We’d love to help you. To improve your chances of getting an answer, here are some tips: [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript does not support associative arrays. Instead use an object, since arrays in JavaScript are objects anyways.

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_arrays.asp